# Check if large size file exist quickly javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, file, web

I have a web page which I need to check if files exist, they vary in files sizes and file type, I have the below code working but for larger files it can take a long time (one of them took 30 seconds) to return a result. What I want to know is there a better way, something that if it was a conversation would look like:

"Are you there file?"

"Yes. I am here and last Sunday I wa.. "

"ya, ya, ya your there shhh"

```
function fileExists(url) { 
    if(url){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
        req.open('GET', url, false)
        req.send()
        return req.status==200
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

So anyone know of a better way which doesn't have to load as much of the file or can cancel the loading once it knows the file is there.

Comment: Have you tried a `HEAD` request?

Answer (score 1):

Try a `HEAD` request:

```
function fileExists(url, callback) { 
   if(url){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
             if (this.readyState === 4) {
                callback(this.status !== 404);
             }
        });
        req.open('HEAD', url, false);
    } else {
       callback(false);
    }
}
```

But you have to use a callback function, because it is an async request

Comment: Sorry had a million things to do the last few days, i was trying you code, and for some reason (believe support was dropped) `req.onreadystatechange = function() {` will not trigger, any ideas?

Comment: I have changed my answer, perhaps this will work for you :)

Comment: It should work alright, figure out why it is not, it always returning readyState 1 ... no idea why the files in question are there. To the google machine let see can I figure out what the hell is going on.